# Conversion from procedure name to type "integer" is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box which is populated from a text box. I type a code and press enter in the textbox and it gets added to the listbox. When I select the item in the listbox, SelectedIndexChanged event has to pass the Listbox.selectedItem to another procedure.

My code looks like this

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(....)
...
...
**FindRefText(ListBox1.SelectedItem)**

End Sub

Private Sub FindRefText(Text1 as String)
....
...
End Sub

The error appears at the line **FindRefText(ListBox1.SelectedItem)**

It says conversion from FindRefText to type "integer" is not valid.

Please help.

Comment: What happens when you press `Enter` in your input TextBox? Anyway, you could pass `ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`, since it's what `FindRefText()` is expecting.

Comment: When I press Enter in the TextBox, it adds the item to the Listbox without any error. But the error happens when the item is pressed and value is passed to procedure.

Comment: @Jimi thank you very much for the quick response. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Yes, well, I meant to ask what type of value you're adding to the ListBox. If you need to deal with string, pass the Text value directly, without conversions. Convert later, eventually.

Comment: I think there is too much code removed for us to be able to help. Is `FindRefText()` being assigned to something?

Comment: The error message says that you're trying to use `FindRefText` in a context where you need an `Integer`, but it's a `Sub` (so it doesn't return anything).

Comment: Dear All, thank you for your response. Actually it was an error from inside the procedure. I was passing the selected item from the listbox to the procedure and extracting parts of it. one part is a number. The listbox item was like this. 1 JOHN 3 4 and I wanted to extract 3 and 4. Then it was passed to database to extract the corresponding text. But due to the error it was extracting additional characters along with the number 3. It is rectified now and working fine. A big thank you for your kind heart.